# dynamically set fit parameters and models with FindFit

Tags: dynamic, fitting

I want to fit a gaussian profile by setting some values dynamically, but `FindFit` returns an error and i can't see the problem.

with a given gaussian:

```
gauss = Table[{x, 
E^(-((x - 10)^2/(2 3^2))) + RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.05}]}, {x, 0, 20,
 0.05}];
```

I set the model to:

```
gaussmodel = b Exp[-((x - d)^2/(2 g^2))];
```

With fitparameters set non-dynamically everything is fine:

```
fit = FindFit[gauss, gaussmodel, {{b, 1}, {d, 10}, {g, 3}}, x]
(*{b -> 1.00439, d -> 10.0109, g -> 2.9804}*)
```

Now I want to set the startingvalues as following:

```
InputField[Dynamic[startvalueb], Number]
InputField[Dynamic[startvalued], Number]
InputField[Dynamic[startvalueg], Number]
Checkbox[Dynamic[bool1]]

xx0 = {Dynamic[
   Which[bool1 == True, {b, Dynamic[startvalueb]}, bool1 == False, 
    Null]], Dynamic[
   Which[bool1 == True, {d, Dynamic[startvalued]}, bool1 == False, 
    Null]], Dynamic[
   Which[bool1 == True, {g, Dynamic[startvalueg]}, bool1 == False, 
    Null]]}
```

witch returns just the form I need, but maybe not??!?
Anyway

```
fi2 = FindFit[gauss, gaussmodel, xx0, x]
```

returns the following error:

```
FindFit::vloc:The variable {b,1} cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values.>>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

```
gauss = Table[{x, E^(-((x - 10)^2/(2 3^2))) + RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.05}]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.05}];
gaussmodel = b Exp[-((x - d)^2/(2 g^2))]; 
Manipulate[If[bool,
             FindFit[gauss, gaussmodel, {{b, bb}, {d, dd}, {g, gg}}, x],
             FindFit[gauss, gaussmodel, {b, d, g}, x]],
          {bool, {True, False}}, {bb, 1}, {dd, 1}, {gg, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: so this works, thanks.
i guess its not possible outside Manipulate?